# Part of a Joomla installation under a subdomain

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, subdomain

I don't think it is possible but I am going to ask about it just in case.

Let's say I have a Joomla running at domain.com. Is it possible to configure Joomla and set up menu items in a way that makes a menu item and its children sit on a subdomain? So, let's say I set up a "blog" menu item that would normally point to domain.com/blog, but instead its address is blog.domain.com.

I know I could just make another subdomain installation but this is exactly what I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. You will obviously need to have another Joomla installation on the subdomain and once done, create a menu item and set the type to "**External Link**". Then simply enter the link of your choice in the parameter.

Comment: Thanks but, like I said, I want to avoid another installation because I would like to share users and parts of content between domain.com and blog.domain.com.